# Splitting two strings with matching indexes into multiple rows in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

I have imported some SQL data into SAS and am trying to figure out how to split two strings with matching indexes into multiple rows using a data statement. I've seen several examples here of how to do this with one string at a time, but not two parallel strings. An example of my problem is below:

**HAVE**

```
ID   TIME_ARRAY           RESPONSE_ARRAY
1    15:23,13:00,12:02    3,4,2
2    17:03,11:07,19:05    1,2,3
3    15:59,10:34,12:12    4,1,2
```

**WANT**

```
ID   TIME    RESPONSE
1    15:23   3
1    13:00   4
1    12:02   2
2    17:03   1
2    11:07   2
2    19:05   3
3    15:59   4
3    10:34   1
3    12:12   2
```

As you can see, the index of the elements in TIME_ARRAY matches the index of the elements in RESPONSE_ARRAY.

Apologies if the problem is unclear, am still a noob with this type of thing.

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers,

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiple string solution isn't particularly different from the one string solution.  Just have one loop and chop both off using the same array indicator.

```
data want;
  set have;
  do _i = 1 to countw(time_array,',');
    time = scan(time_array,_i,',');
    response = scan(response_array,_i,',');
    output;
  end;
  keep id time response;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably also want to convert those values into numbers once you get them separated out from the string they are in.

You can use the `INPUT()` function to do that.  So building on the code from Joe's answer you get something like this.

```
data want;
  set have;
  length time response 8;
  format time time. ;
  do _i = 1 to countw(time_array,',');
    time = input(scan(time_array,_i,','),time.);
    response = input(scan(response_array,_i,','),32.);
    output;
  end;
  keep id time response;
run;
```